# Grid view in asp is not showing in the webapp

Tags: html, sql, asp.net

**This is the Employee.aspx file**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="Azure_Migrated_App.Employee" %>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <h1>Employee in Our Database:</h1>
                <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server">
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**This is the Employee.aspx.cs file**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Azure_Migrated_App
{
    public partial class Employee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected GridView GetGridview1()
        {
            return Gridview1;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, GridView gridview1)
        {
            //First Establish the connection string to your database.This we can read from the web.config file.
            //so first create an entry to store the database connection string in your web.config file
            string dbConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBaseConnectionStrings"].ConnectionString;

            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Employee";//this return all records from database.
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection1.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdpter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, sqlConnection1);
                DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                dataAdpter.Fill(dtbl);
                Gridview1.DataSource = dtbl;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
            NewMethod();

        }

        private void NewMethod()
        {
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the web.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DataBaseConnectionStrings" connectionString="Data Source=WIN2019\WEBAPP;Initial Catalog=employee;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********;Max Pool Size=5000;Connect Timeout=60" providerName="System.Data.SQLClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

I uploaded below the database photo , the problem is that the grid view is not displaying at all

**This is the database**
[image: Database]

I uploaded below the database photo , the problem is that the grid view is not displaying at all

Comment: Do you actually have records in the database? Why are you calling DataBind twice on the GridView?

Comment: yes there is data , i added it beacuase the fisrt time it didn't work ... but if i remove it too it's still the same

Comment: You've only answered one of my questions. Can you please address the other one? And here's a third question: what happens if you add this attribute in your GridView markup `EmptyDataText="No records found"`?

Comment: i answered it , i added the second databind because it didn't work , i thought it will fix it , now i removed it , and it still not working , i will add the field you proposed and see what will happen

Comment: i added it the page is still blank

Comment: Databinding twice wouldn't solve anything, it's just makes the code messier without accomplishing anything. I suggest you start verifying all the basic assumptions about your app. Are you publishing correctly? Are you hosting the site on your own machine or some other? Does the connection string point to the same exact database that you are viewing in SSMS? What happens if you add other content to the page besides the GridView - does it appear? If you set a breakpoint in your code and inspect the DataTable at the point of DataBind(), does the DataTable contain any data in your IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, I would suggest you use the connection builder. If you  create a setting, then it is automatic placed in web.config for you.

So, say this:

[image]

So, use the above connection builder. It will enable you to not only setup a connection, but also test it, and do so LONG before you write any code.
And use the test connection button, so this:

[image]

So, now with this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table">

        </asp:GridView>
```

And code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }


    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VHotelsA  ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And we get this:

[image]

Now, with above done?

(and NEVER skip using the !IsPostBack - you can't build a working page if you skip the test for first page load, and put the GV load code inside of that code stub on page load.